# fetch oneToMany and manyToOne using hibernate and @JsonIgnore

Tags: java, hibernate

I have table A that is related to table B in oneToMany relation 
(meaning B is related in manyToOne)  both of the relations are set to EAGER
I saw that unless i put the following annotation

```
@JsonIgnore
```

on the manyToOne (meaning on table B ) I get an error (infinite loop ) 
what I am coming from table C to table B in order to get the data from table A it is coming empty (because of this annotation ) 
my question is : how do I get the information from table A coming  table B (maybe the  @JsonIgnore is wrong ? ) 
my hibernate version is 5.1.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@JsonIgnore says: no need this field to be shown in JSON. The Jackson library will not try to populate this field.

But once you remove @JsonIgnore it will lead Jackson to endless number of calls to get B data for A and then A data for B, this calls comes to Hibernate and you getting an error.

You can

1. rethink your schema
2. use DTO objects
3. Build custom queries and then build response

I would check option 2 and probably 1 first.

Comment: thank you  , I was afraid of this answer  :-)  , I will go with option 1.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this has anything to do with Hibernate.
When exactly do you get the error? I assume on marshalling the data.

And that is exactly, why `@JsonIgnore` helps. 
Without it, marshalling an object of class B includes the A object. And marshalling the object of A includes all related B objects. You get the problem?

Comment: thank you but I dont understand what "marshling"  means...in any case how do I solve my problem ?

Comment: @RMagen you could start with googling what "marshalling" is.