# hibernate link 2 java files to the same DB table

Tags: java, hibernate

as a continue to this question

[fetch oneToMany and manyToOne using hibernate and @JsonIgnore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52718936/fetch-onetomany-and-manytoone-using-hibernate-and-jsonignore)

I have an issue with the JsonIgnore 
I was thinking to build one object that has the JsonIgnore annotation 
and one object that does not have it.
when I am trying to use the new object it is still using the old object - what am i missing ?

this is the new code (CategoryIgnoreJson  is the new class that I created )

```
    @GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("getCategoriesQandA")
public List<CategoryIgnoreJson> getCategoriesQandA() {
    ediUtils = new EDIUtils(SYSTEM_NAME, USER_NAME);
    Init(ediUtils);
    ediUtils.writeToLog("get Categories , questions and answers ");
    List<CategoryIgnoreJson> categoriesArray;

    categoriesArray = categoryIgnoreJsonRepository.getEffective();

    return categoriesArray;

}
```

I also created new repository

```
public interface CategoryIgnoreJsonRepository extends JpaRepository<CategoryIgnoreJson, Long>{
@Transactional 
@Modifying
@Query("update  Category set expiration_date = current_date() where category_id = ?1 ")
void expireCategory(Long id );  


@Query("from Category where function ('coalesce' ,effectiveDate ,current_date() ) <= current_date() "
        + "and function('coalesce' ,expirationDate , to_date('50001231','yyyymmdd')) > current_date() ")
List<CategoryIgnoreJson> getEffective( );
```

}

I can see in the log file that the old Category is still called 
I also changed the table name in old category from categories to categories1 (just to validate that this code is called ) and got the expected error

```
edi_ms.categories1" does not exist
```

how do I call the new class ? what am I missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue 
I also needed to change the select to

```
    @Query("from CategoryIgnoreJson ..."
```

also change the value of the mapped by to refer to the name of the object that is is mapped to in the parrent (in CatagoryIgnoreJson.java )

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "categoryIgnoreJson")
@Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
@NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
public List<QuestionIgnoreJson> getQuestions() {
    return this.questions;enter code here
```